# Fullcalendar columns placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to add placeholders to columns there rows has time. For example 10am so on right all columns have to had placeholders with text 10am and only rows with time on left.

like example below:

[image]

I was searching all over the internet but didn't find anything what would worked for me.

Comment: Nice question, but I don't think you can accomplish that. Take a look at FullCalendar's DOM and you'll see it is built based on a table. The "columns" where you see the hours is a `<td>` and there's another `<td>` that fills the entire "row" matching all days, so there's no cell per day per hour.